# Why is the global Step not incrementing in custom Tensorflow model function

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I've been trying to update [this tutorial](https://github.com/mouradmourafiq/tensorflow-lstm-regression) to the latest version of tensorflow ie 0.12 and I've hit a snag in the custom model function definition to train the lstm model.

```
def _lstm_model(X, y):
    stacked_lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(
        lstm_cells(rnn_layers),
        state_is_tuple=True)

   global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)
   X = tf.cast(X, tf.float32)
   y = tf.cast(y, tf.float32)
   x_ = tf.unpack(X, axis=1, num=time_steps)
   output, layers = tf.nn.rnn(stacked_lstm, x_, dtype=dtypes.float32)
   output = dnn_layers(output[-1], dense_layers)
   (predictions, loss) = learn.models.linear_regression(output, y)

   if optim == 'Adagrad':
       print("using AdagradOptimizer")
       optimizer = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(learning_rate)
   else:
       optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)

   train_op = optimizer.minimize(
       loss,
       global_step=global_step)

    return (predictions, loss, train_op)
```

I've tried both specifying the global step and not specifying it - and I've ended up with the same result - the step remains at 0 with loss being optimized and this continues until I stop the entire script. The code below is what I use to create an Estimator and try to fit the model.

```
regressor = learn.SKCompat(learn.Estimator(
model_fn=lstm_model(TIMESTEPS,
                    RNN_LAYERS,
                    DENSE_LAYERS,
                    optim='Adagrad',
                    learning_rate=0.03)))

regressor.fit(x=X['train'],
          y=y['train'],
          batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
          steps=TRAINING_STEPS
          )
```

Comment: I guess the key is to use [`tf.train.get_or_create_global_step`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/get_or_create_global_step), which was added later than `v0.12`.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that the adamOptimizer was not to be used on it's own - but with the neural network that I had created. The following edit on my code - helped me achieve what I wanted to :

```
# create model and features
stacked_lstm = tf.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(
    lstm_cells(params['rnn_layers']),
    state_is_tuple=True)
features = tf.cast(features, tf.float32)
targets = tf.cast(targets, tf.float32)
features = tf.unpack(features, axis=1, num=params['time_steps'])
output, layers = tf.nn.rnn(stacked_lstm, features, dtype=dtypes.float32)
output = dnn_layers(output[-1], params['dense_layers'])

# Define Loss
(predictions, loss) = learn.models.linear_regression(output, targets)

# train_op
train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(
    loss=loss,
    global_step=contrib.framework.get_global_step(),
    learning_rate=params['learning_rate'],
    optimizer='Adagrad'
)
```

Here I created the neural Network layers first and then tried to find the optimization on that layer - this is what seemed to have caused me problems.
The tensorflow documentation helped me out quite a bit - hence I was able to run the code on tensorflow - v0.12.